# AppArmor error Gnome Software Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, uefi, apparmor, gnome-software

I'm very new to this stuff. I had a problem with snap-software so I purged it and installed gnome-software and I'm seeing the below error message.

> Sorry, something went wrong:
>
> An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":-1.133" (uid=1000 pid=6370 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-software " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.fwupd" member="getdevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.32" (uid=0 pid=908 comm="/snap/uefi-fw-tools/18/-libexec/fwupd/fwupd "label="snap.uefi-fw-tools.fwupd (enforce)"

I was not able to manage to get a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04, I think the boot drive might have been corrupted (flashed from macOS), I've had some other errors I've dealt with like the Wifi card not being recognised but I can't seem to work this one out. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems I fixed it. [ sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service ]
It's always the simplest things.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error today on my Ubuntu 23.10 and found this question. I tried the solution of the [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/1133292/ramzataz) in the comment but it didn't work. I looked in the Ubuntu forums and found the answers in this [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2492198).

> The problem was caused by UEFI secure boot being enabled, which
> prevented the firmware from updating properly. I disabled it for other
> reasons before initiating the firmware update and now it checked
> out.

Since I have already disabled the secure boot for installing Ubuntu on my machine, I looked for another solution.

> I noticed this error while dev testing Noble. I did update it > Got
> that error > Rebooted the system and checked again. Even though it
> said it errored, it did update mine anyway.
>
> You might want to reboot and check if yours is updated.

After restarting, I can see my firmware got updated to the latest version.

[image: firmware-screenshot]